# Refresh recoil atom with async fetch, after it has been updated locally?

Tags: reactjs, state-management, recoiljs

I have an application where I show a set of invites, each invite has a set of answers connected, that the users can update,

I have the following recoil state:

```
export const answerState = atom<AnswerDto[] | undefined>({
  key: 'Answers',
  default: selector({
    key: 'Answers/Default',
    get: async ({ get }) => {
      const id = get(currentInviteIdState)
      if (!id) {
        return undefined
      }
      const response = await getAnswerInviteId(id)
      return response.data
    },
  }),
})
```

Updating the states is done with a react useCallback(), like:

```
export function useUpdateAnswer() {
  const [currentState, setState] = useRecoilState(answerState)

  return useCallback(
    (answer: AnswerDto) => {
      postAnswerUpdate(answer).then(({ data }) =>
        setState([
          ...(currentState?.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id) || []),
          data,
        ]),
      )
    },
    [currentState, setState],
  )
}
```

this part does work fine, I can update the AnswerState, and get the result shown in my app. But if I then update the initial `currentInviteIdState`, after I have updated a couple of answers, recoil doesn't fetch a new set of answers for this new invite.

It seems that this is as designed, according to https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/asynchronous-data-queries#query-default-atom-values, so what am I doing wrong? I've been browsing through the docs for examples, but so far without any luck.

Comment: When you call setState you replace the selector that is making the requests for you with an object, meaning any subsequent currentInviteIdState does not result in requests to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have read the documentation better.. Using atomFamily and selectorFamily let me do what I want, as I can specify an id.

```
const answerState = atomFamily<AnswerDto[] | undefined, number>({
  key: 'Answers',
  default: selectorFamily({
    key: 'Answers/Default',
    get: (id) => ({ get }) => {
      if (!id) {
        return undefined
      }
      return getAnswerInviteId(id).then(({data}) => data)
    },
  }),
})

export const answersByOtherState = selector({
  key: 'answersbyId',
  get: ({get}) => {
    const id = get(currentInviteId)
    return get(AnswerState(id))
  }
})
```

Comment: can we combine a react-query to fetch the data so that we can use its features too.